# React accessing a parent method from generated children components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and so I don't know if what I want is possible.

Consider the following React component:

```
export default class BBCode extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        {parser.toReact(this.props.content.content)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I am using a library that renders a string that contains bb code to html tags and in some cases React components. That is being done by the function `{parser.toReact}`.

I want to access a method in this component through any components that are generated by the `parser.toReact` function.

Is there perhaps a way to pass a prop to this function which would then be applied to any components that are generated?

Comment: Does `parse.toReact` return an array of strings and/or react components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could attach extra props to the children with [`React.cloneElement`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement). Assuming `parse.toReact` returns an array of strings or React elements, you can clone each element and add your callback as an additional prop:

```
export default class BBCode extends Component {
  render () {
    // every React element will receive `myCustomCallback` as a prop
    const elements = parser
      .toReact(this.props.content.content)
      .map(elem => React.isValidElement(elem)
        ? React.cloneElement(elem, {
            myCustomCallback: this.myCustomCallback
          })
        : elem
      );

    return (
      <div>
        {elements}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Super interesting approach, never considered this. Gonna try it out now!

Comment: This is awesome and works great for what I need. Does React.cloneElement carry a performance penalty?

Comment: Glad to help mate. As far as your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35616029/react-createelement-vs-cloneelement